# Parameter passes to a onclick function in PHP says undefined

Tags: php, function, parameters, onclick, undefined

```
$countt=$this->ex_data['items']['Count'];

<input type="button" class="Button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelItem(this,{$this->ex_data['Row']['number']},$countt);">
```

I have defined count as shown above and passing to a onclik function of a button in PHP , but when I hit cancel button for the first time it says undefined for the value of count but at this point if I hit refresh and click the cancel button again it works fine. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not printing the data:

```
$countt=$this->ex_data['items']['Count'];

print('<input type="button" class="Button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelItem(this,{'.$this->ex_data['Row']['number'].'},'.$countt.');">');
```